# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in a EAR

Tags: java, wildfly, jco

I create an EAR in which there is a WAR and deploy to the wildfly server. The project need sapjco3.jar to run. I put the jar at server and create a XML in EAR to use it.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <!-- Make sub deployments isolated by default, so they cannot see each others classes without a Class-Path entry -->
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <!-- This corresponds to the top level deployment. For a war this is the war's module, for an ear -->
    <!-- This is the top level ear module, which contains all the classes in the EAR's lib folder     -->
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
        <!-- This allows you to define additional dependencies, it is the same as using the Dependencies: manifest attribute -->
        <dependencies>
            <module name="deployment.nana-app.ear" export="true" />
            <module name="deployment.sapjco3.jar" export="true" />
        </dependencies>
        <!-- These add additional classes to the module. In this case it is the same as including the jar in the EAR's lib directory -->
        <resources> 
        </resources>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

The deployment succeed but when I use it below error occurred.

```
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sap.conn.jco.JCo
    ... 206 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sap.conn.jco.JCo
    at com.sap.conn.jco.JCoDestinationManager.getDestination(JCoDestinationManager.java:77)
    at com.SAPcall.SAPcallBean.ContractCreate(SAPcallBean.java:586)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

The jar location is correct because I have another WAR use it and that one works.So what's wrong with my project? Do I need to add configuration the war? Thx.

Comment: Did you put the dll/so in the correct place ?

Comment: Is the JAR deployed separately or included in your EAR?

Comment: @ehsavoie you mean sapjco3.dll? where should I put it? In the system32 folder or the jco unzipped folder. I already unzip the sap jco jar folder and created a environment variable for it.

Comment: I'm not sure, tbh I would rather create a jboss module following what is done for artemis for example. I don't know how this module is loaded by sap

Comment: @ehsavoie you mean create a global module in standalaone.xml? How tocreate it? Thx.

Comment: @James R. Perkins the jar is put in the deployment directory and not included in the jar.

Comment: No I was thinking of a module in $WILDFLY_HOME/modules